# variable creation for unbalanced dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset where observations are `ID` `year` `event_type` `event_date`. There are an unbalanced number of observations per `ID` `year`. To be specific these are battle-outcomes within conflict-years. Each battle has a date and a type(outcome).

What I want to do is create a variable based on the number of events of a certain type within the subset of `ID` `year`. So:

by `ID`

by `year`

sum of `event_type == x`

I understand how to do this with a regular for loop, but I understand I should use tapply() since I have different numbers of observations per `ID`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then:

```
aggregate(event_type ~ ID + year, subset(df,event_type=="x"), length)
```

Comment: I like this solution. Is there a similarly elegant way to append the sum of the number of events of type x to obs that match on ID & year? I am just going to run a merge command.

Comment: Given you have unbalanced data, merge is the simplest way, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

```
library(plyr)
df <-data.frame(ID=sample(11:20,25,replace=T),year=sample(1900:1905,25,replace=T),event_type=sample(c("win","lose"),25,replace=T))

# To see this sample data sorted by ID and year.
arrange(df,ID,year)
  ID year event_type
1  11 1901        win
2  11 1904        win
3  11 1910       lose
4  12 1920       lose
5  13 1900        win
6  13 1905        win
7  13 1906       lose
8  13 1912        win
9  13 1920       lose
10 14 1906        win
11 14 1918       lose
12 14 1920        win
13 15 1909        win
14 15 1919        win
15 16 1916        win
16 16 1920       lose
17 18 1901       lose
18 18 1910       lose
19 18 1912       lose
20 18 1920        win
21 19 1916        win
22 19 1916        win
23 19 1917       lose
24 20 1901       lose
25 20 1914       lose



   result <- ddply(df, .(ID,year,event_type),summarise, event_count=length(event_type))

    >result
   ID year event_type event_count
1  11 1903        win           1
2  11 1905       lose           1
3  12 1903       lose           1
4  12 1905        win           1
5  13 1902        win           1
6  13 1905       lose           1
7  14 1903        win           1
8  15 1901        win           2
9  15 1903       lose           1
10 15 1905        win           1
11 16 1904        win           1
12 17 1904       lose           1
13 18 1900       lose           2
14 18 1900        win           1
15 18 1902       lose           1
16 18 1904        win           1
17 18 1905        win           1
18 19 1901       lose           1
19 19 1902        win           1
20 19 1903       lose           1
21 19 1903        win           1
22 20 1901        win           1
23 20 1904        win           1
```

Lets say you only wanted to tally the wins and not the losses, then something like:

```
result <- ddply(subset(df,event_type=="win"), .(ID,year,event_type),summarise, event_count=length(event_type))

>result
   ID year event_type event_count
1  11 1903        win           1
2  12 1905        win           1
3  13 1902        win           1
4  14 1903        win           1
5  15 1901        win           2
6  15 1905        win           1
7  16 1904        win           1
8  18 1900        win           1
9  18 1904        win           1
10 18 1905        win           1
11 19 1902        win           1
12 19 1903        win           1
13 20 1901        win           1
14 20 1904        win           1
```